# Facebook Live's Emoji unicode convert issue

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, emoji

Did anyone know how can i convert facebook emoji from \ud83e\udd79 into emoji [image] in php?

I tried this, but still cannot, as the emoji is load from image from facebook, got any otherway to do this?
and tried php emoji also cannot, there is no unicode for that..

https://github.com/iamcal/php-emoji/

`$str2 = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) { return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*',$match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16'); }, $str2);`

Comment: `json_decode('"\ud83e\udd79"')`

Comment: Hi, it will not display the icon, it will display like a square 

Comment: Works fine here, https://3v4l.org/NJ7ri If your site is not using UTF-8 encoding, you might have to convert the result into yours.

Comment: Hi, is any library needed? i tried this https://3v4l.org/NJ7ri, but it alsi display square for me.., even i use other computer also same, i can't get the emoji icon

Comment: That displays  for me, same as my version. If _that_ shows as a square for you here as well, then your system/browser must be missing the ability to show that emoji natively.